# What is the point of locking votes on meta posts automatically after 5 minutes?

Tags: discussion, locked-votes

> <sup>It looks like this question was already asked on main meta site:</sup>
>   [Don't lock votes on Meta sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/171694/dont-lock-votes-on-meta-sites)
>   <sub>but I will leave this question here to show that some of as are still interested in this subject.</sub>

I understand that main site is trying to save us from things like tactical down-voting from users who want to gain more reputation points (which also means more privileges, glory, fame, unicorns and so on).

But here on meta votes can't affect reputation.
So what is the point of locking them here?

---

When I'm reading posts on meta I'm voting them based on my current understanding of subject. Often I am casting vote on first answer which I am agreeing with. But after reading other answers/comments I sometimes find one which conflicts with one I already voted on. When I am agreeing with this new point of view I would like to retract my previous vote since I no longer see that answer as entirely correct.

Problem is that after 5 minutes from casting votes are locked.

It looks like this mechanism only prevents us from changing our minds. So it is like saying that we should pay more attention to how we distribute our votes. But in that case are we expected to read all answers and comments before casting votes? If yes are we expected to wait some amount of time (days?) before we can safely assume that no post/comment will appear which could add new important aspect to discussion so we could safely cast our votes?

Comment: Related [question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/171694/295232) on Meta Stack Exchange.

Comment: @Glorfindel Thanks, this question is duplicate of one from uber-meta. Will add that to question.

Comment: Well, surely for the usual reason, programmers don't like to handle special cases in their code that have few practical benefits.  The SE devs can usually rely on the community leads to find a minor technicality to defeat the request :)

Comment: You can always make a minor edit and then reverse your vote, but I also don't see why votes need to be locked on meta.